# If linked from example.com show content

Tags: php, html, input

Is there any possibility to show html content on a site if the user was linked from a specific site? If not, do not show content.

I have a `<input>` login form and want to set value if the user comes from a special site.

Comment: utm tags ? it will depend on the url put on the site from where the user is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too reliable but you can try:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://www.google.com") {
    echo "secret content";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Kev meant that it won't always work, simply because it's not too reliable! Now if you want Kev to explain _why_ it's not reliable, just ask that.